# C++ using animations from Flash or similar

Tags: c++, flash, animation

I want to program a game, and I want to do it in C++, because everyone seems to agree this is the best way to program a game. What I really want, though, is the ability to animate something, swap images around during runtime, and retain the animation. Also, the ability to pin graphics to certain parts of other graphics, or group graphics together. I know for sure Actionscript and Flash can do both of these. It's especially easy in Flash because I can visually see the animation and swap symbols via Actionscript to change it to what I want at whichever frame I want. Now, I know that it's fairly simple to swap images during runtime in C++ as well, but in C++, (from my understanding) I would have to animate via code and I would have to manually move each graphic separately for the graphics to stay together. Is there's a way where I can animate in Flash, then use those animations and swap images in C++? Or, if there's some other way to accomplish the same thing, without using Flash? (don't mind using bitmaps)

Comment: Just an example of what I want to do: say you have a character where the player gets to decide the hairstyle and weapon. I don't want to include every single permutation of hairstyle and weapon, so I would pin or group a base hair and weapon to the character's head and hands, and let the game swap the graphic during runtime based on the player's choices. The animations should stay (swinging the weapon around, hair following character's head) regardless of what the player chooses.

Comment: I would look into a game engine.  What you are asking is for spritesheets and some type of scene graph which are easy enough to code in themselves but an engine would have it written for you already.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you should just program your game in Flash and ActionScript, if you're already experienced with those tools and your game can fit in them. Programming a game in C++ is a difficult and complex task, necessary for difficult and complex games but often overkill for simple and fun design. If you just want to design games, go with the simplest tool that lets you make your prototype!

If your game is too big to implement in Flash, consider using [XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/centrum-xna.aspx), or a prebuilt game engine such as [Ogre](http://www.ogre3d.org/) or [Unity](http://unity3d.com/). XNA is in C♯ but even that is good enough for any game that a one-man team could build.

[Scaleform](http://gameware.autodesk.com/scaleform) lets you embed Flash in a C++/DirectX game, but as you can see it is rather complicated to employ. We have one engineer and three artists dedicated full-time to Scaleform UI on our project, to give a sense of how much work it is.

Comment: I COULD do it in Actionscript, without a doubt. I anticipate that my project will be pretty big, and I've played large Actionscript games before, and it starts to slow down after an hour or so due to (possibly) memory leaks beyond my control, and only seems to run reasonably well on Windows machines only. I could try Actionscript anyway, but I want to explore the C++ option first. I have far more experience in C++ than Actionscript so I'm not trying to move away from familiar territory or anything like that.

Comment: @TheRugi  Oh, if you've lots of experience with C++ then definitely try an engine like Unity. That'll handle all the annoying machinery of loading images and managing scenegraphs for you, not to mention opening a game window, getting a DirectX context, etc.  The term of art for connecting one sprite entity to another in this way is "parenting", as in one element becomes a child of the other under the entity graph; the same way that you'd have a character holding a weapon.